# Is it possible that BalancerMember retries connection?

Tags: apache-httpd

We are using apache2 Proxy balancer and we have setup like this:

```
  <Proxy balancer://app_server_1 maxattempts=10>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:5033
  </Proxy>
```

Is it possible to setup this balancer to retry connection to http://127.0.0.1:5033 and does sleep for 10 seconds or so each time it fails to connect. Sometime like try sleep for 10 seconds after each attempt to connect?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where you want your ten seconds, I think you want [either `timeout` or `retry`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz The option timeout is not related to establish the connection with backend (it is about "The number of seconds Apache httpd waits for data sent by / to the backend." - nothing about establishing connection to backend. The option retry in BalancerMember section is also not related to this. It is about "If the connection pool worker to the backend server is in the error state, Apache httpd will not forward any requests to that server until the timeout expires. ". I wonder if there is something like Sleep_between_connection_attempts.